# Export DataGrid to PDF using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview

How can I convert datagrid to PDF?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is "how do you want it laid out?".  You can use something like iTextSharp, which is a great library, but not that good at laying out simple stuff like this.  I would instead create an RDLC-based report using VS's Report Designer, and then use the [LocalReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.aspx) class's Render() method to render the report, using your dataset as the data source, to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

iTextSharp is an open source library you could use to generate and manipulate the PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to get data from DataGrid into your collection:

Create class, for example, employee:

```
public class employee 
{ 
    public string name; 
    public string address; 
}
```

Then create collection of employees:

```
List<employee> employee_list = new List<employee>();
```

Read data from DataGrid into your collection (using foreach loop, for example).

2. Now you need to print your collection into PDF file:

I would advise [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/inf) library, as it has easy syntax and lots of functionality. You can print your DataGrid using Paragraphs or Table.

If you want to use table, this will be your code setting datasource to the table, the rest of the work the library will do by itself:

```
using Gehtsoft.PDFFlow; 
DocumentBuilder.New() 
    .AddSection() 
        .AddTable() 
            .AddColumnToTable("Name") 
            .AddColumnToTable("Address") 
        .SetDataSource(employee_list) 
.ToDocument() 
    .Build("Result.pdf");
```

Or you can loop through your collection and add cells by yourself:

```
var PDFtable = DocumentBuilder.New().AddSection() 
    .AddTable() 
        .AddColumnToTable("Name") 
        .AddColumnToTable("Address"); 
foreach(var emp in employee_list) 
{ 
    PDFtable 
        .AddRow() 
            .AddCellToRow(emp.Name) 
            .AddCell(emp.Address); 
} 
PDFtable 
    .ToDocument() 
        .Build("Result.PDF");
```

Here are plenty of source code examples of creating PDF file in C# : [Source code](https://go.pdfflow.io/src).

Hope, this will help.